# Lotka-Volterra equations modified

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Okay, so I'm just learning about the Lotka-Volterra and  the question I have regards the following model:

$dx/dt = x(1-y/2)$

$dy/dt = -y(1 - (x/0.8) + (x^2)/4)$

I need to state what term has been added to the standard Lotka-Volterra equations and the effect it has.
Now $dx/dt$ is standard and I want to say $((x^2)/4)$ is the term that has been added to $dy/dt$.  Surely this cannot be correct however as 0.8 is not a constant positive integer, which I thought was one of the conditions of the Lotka-Volterra.

I have $dy/dt = -y(1 - (x/4)(5 - x))$ but I'm not sure how this helps.

Many thanks in advance for any help/explanation.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I thought it had to be an integer? Because we are considering populations but does that not matter for the model?

Comment: There is no restriction to integers.  Despite the fact that this is a model for populations, $x$ and $y$ are continuous variables.  In an actual application, the numbers would be scaled, so "$1$" in $x$ or $y$ might represent a million individuals.

Comment: Okay many thanks for the replies

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, in this class of differential systems, for every initial condition near the fixed point of smallest abscissa, the behaviour is cyclic, but for every initial condition not inside the closed curve around this fixed point and not on the curves intersecting at the fixed point with largest abscissa, $x(t)\to\infty$ and $y(t)\to0$, which corresponds to an extinction of the population of predators and an explosion of the population of preys.

Below, as an example, the system $$x'=x-xy\quad y'=yx(3-x)-2y$$
The fixed points are $(0,0)$ (saddle), $(1,1)$ (center) and $(2,1)$ (saddle). The level curves are $$C(h):\quad yx^2\exp(-y-3x+x^2/2)=h$$ and the critical (closed) level curve is the loop part of $C(4e^{-5})$.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

0.8 is a constant, and yes, you are right, $x^2/4$ is the term that has been added to the standard model.

The standard model only contains a birth/death process, f.e. $dx/dt = x$ and mass-action law terms to model the predator-prey relationship.

Comment: Thanks, sorry my post was poorly worded. I was under the impression that you would always have an integer for X in (1-x/X) as I thought that is an equlibrium value?